# How to name and create file in a loop

Tags: c, stdio

In C, I want to create and open text files to write data into, but the problem is I want to name the files on the go, such as

```
FILE *ptr;

for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
   fopen_s(&ptr,"i.txt","w");
   operations to fill data into file i.txt;
   fclose(ptr);
}
```

such that I will create file 0.txt, 1.txt, 2.txt ... 999.txt.

How is this possible? I checked open and rename functions, but couldn't find a way to do.

Thank you so much for all your help.
Best,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `snprintf` to set the file number:

```
FILE *ptr;
char name[FILENAME_MAX];

for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
   snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "%d.txt", i);
   fopen_s(&ptr, name, "w");
   //operations to fill data into file i.txt;
   fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: `FILENAME_MAX` is more appropriate than the magic constant 256.

Comment: thanks, but when i run in VS 2008, i get these errors: : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _snprintf referenced in function _main
: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals do you know what should I do?

Comment: @user1450005 try `_snprintf` or `_snprintf_s`

Comment: thanks _snprintf works, but the first problem remains, it only creates one file, with a junk name, first file should be 0.txt but it creates 24322525.txt which is incorrect and doesn't create a new file, I appreciate anymore help, thank you

Comment: do you think snprintf does the required job?

Comment: @user1450005 yes you were right that should have been `i` sorry about that I typed to quickly.