# How to create create a text files sequence in C

Tags: c, file, sequence, fopen, fclose

I want to create text files sequence like...

> student1.txt
>   student2.txt
>   student3.txt
>   ...

How to do it?

I have a sample code, but its not working for my problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int index;

    for(index=1; index<4; index++)
    {
        fp=fopen("student[index].txt","w");
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up on `snprintf()`.

Comment: Already asked question. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432535/how-to-name-and-create-file-in-a-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a a fixed string "student[index].txt" rather than making a string with the number you want in it.

```
void main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  int index;
  char fname[100];

  for(index=1; index<4; index++)
  {
    sprintf(fname, "student%d.txt", index);
    fp=fopen(fname,"w");
    fclose(fp);
  }
}
```

Comment: should be sprintf(fname, "student%d.txt", index); : )

Comment: You'll better use `snprintf` (even if in your particular case, `sprintf` is safe, since `fname` is very wide)

Answer (score 1):

You can't put variables inside of a string constant like that.  You need to construct the string you want using `sprintf`:

```
for(index=1; index<4; index++)
{
    char name[20];
    sprintf(name, "student%d.txt", i);
    fp=fopen(name,"w");
    fclose(fp);
}
```